# How to interpret results of GLM logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

[image]

This is for low birthrate. How do I interpret this? I know that "marital not married" and "weeks" are significant.

Answer (score 5):

The exact interpretation depends on how the predictor variables are coded. Recall that the logistic GLM can be expressed as
$$
\log_e \left(\frac{p}{1-p} \right)=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1+ \ldots+\beta_n x_n
$$
where, say, $p$ is the probability of child having low birth-weight (and therefore $\frac{p}{1-p} $ is the *odds* of low birth-weight). The values of the $\beta$ coefficients indicate how the log-odds change for a unitary increase in the predictor. This can be transformed to the (multiplicative) change in odds by exponentiating the coefficient; in other words, an increase in $x_1$ of 1 corresponds to a multiplicative increase in the odds (of low birth-weight) by $e^{\beta}$.

For a dichotomous predictor, as I assume is the case for example for `maritalnot married`, $e^{\beta}$ can be directly interpreted as the odds ratio between groups. For example, if $x_1 \in \left\{0,1\right\}$ represented the marital status, then keeping everything else constant and comparing the odds between not-married ($x_1=1$) and married ($x_1=0$) would give 
$$
\frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1+ \beta_2x_2+ \ldots+\beta_n x_n}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1+ \beta_2x_2+\ldots+\beta_n x_n}} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1+ \beta_2x_2+ \ldots+\beta_n x_n}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_2x_2+\ldots+\beta_n x_n}} = e^{\beta_1} = e^{0.72...} \approx 2.075
$$
This would suggest (if my interpretation of your variables is correct) that being not married is linked with an increase in the odds of low birth-weight approximately by a factor of 2.

Comment: (+1) Nicely done except for the all-too-easy slip into causal language.  How about "being not married *is linked with* an increase in the odds...."

Comment: spot on @rolando2 :) I changed it now

Comment: How about this interpretation: *"All else being equal, not being married is associated with an approximately 2-fold increase in the odds of low birthweight compared to being married."* This makes it clear that the odds are adjusted for smoking status, age, etc. Here, "all else being equal" means "among those with the same smoking status, age, etc.". Also, using the words "is associated with" explicitly indicate that we're NOT talking about causation.